# I'm looking for a card game with a deck of noun cards and a deck of occupation cards

Tags: identify-this-game

It's a party game, players have a hand of noun cards and the 'in' person each round picks an occupation card up and chooses one of the occupations on the card like "I'm a firefighter".  Then all the other players pick two of their noun cards to make an 'item' and do their best to sell their item to the player for their occupation, and the 'it' player chooses the most convincing.  It's very silly and very fun and I can't remember the name or find it anywhere, please help!

Answer (score 4):

In this instance it's Snake Oil. You combine two nouns from your hand to sell to the active player to help them in their occupation

Fun-Employed is similar in that the active player has a job posting to fill and players have a 4-hand 'resume' and can swap cards from their hand with a set of 10 cards on the table to best tailor their hand to the role.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're describing [**Funemployed**](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/142296/funemployed) or [**Snake Oil**](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/113289/snake-oil).

Comment: It would be a good idea to include a small synopsis of the games along with the links. As your answer stands right now, it will be a whole lot less useful if the links break in the future.